# How can I prevent my Stream<List<T>> from reading all the list items when 1 changes?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with the firestore and flutter and I have the following Stream

```
  Stream<List<GroupInvitationModel>> groupInvitationStream() => _firestore
      .collection(APIRoutes.userGroupInvitations(user.id))
      .where('recieverId', isEqualTo: user.id)
      .where('isAccepted', isNull: true)
      .snapshots()
      .map((snapshot) =>
          snapshot.documents.map((document) => GroupInvitationModel.fromFirestore(document)).toList(growable: false));
```

When 1 items updates all the documents get read again. These are many unnecessary reads. How could I make it so that it will only read the file that has been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When 1 items updates all the documents get read again.

That's actually not what's happening here.  As long as the stream is active, the documents read from the query are cached in memory.  The first callback will deliver the entire set of documents.  If a document gets changed, only that one document is read from the cloud, but the entire set of documents is delivered to the callback again, delivered from cache as needed.

If you want to know which documents changed, you can check the delivered [QuerySnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) class for that.  The `documentChanges` property will tell you what changed.  Anything unchanged is not read from the cloud.

Comment: Wow did not know that. I guess I made a wrong assumption, thanks for the clarification!